# How to change the timezone on CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, timezone

Does anyone know how to change the timezone on CentOS 7?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-linux-6-7-changing-timezone-command-line/) should be enough to

```
timedatectl set-timezone <your_time_zone>
```