# Changing Date using date command along with time zone

Tags: date

How to change the date using `date` command along with changing the time zone. Since "IST" as time zone is not setting to Indian standard time (which is UTC +05:30) (I am looking for a solution specific to CentOS 7 )

Comment: Please mention distro and version in body to get precise answer specific to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most Unices, the system clock should be set to UTC time.  The timezone should then be set to the appropriate value by either setting the `TZ` environment variable to a value such as `Asia/Calcutta` (on a user-by-user basis), or by setting the system's timezone. The `date` command is not used for setting the timezone.

Setting the system's timezone may be done differently on different Unices.  On Ubuntu, it is done through the command `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.  On OpenBSD it is done by creating a symbolic link from `/etc/localtime` to the correct timezone file under `/usr/share/zoneinfo` (e.g. `/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Calcutta`).

Answer (score 0):

When setting the date with `date`, it changes the time stored by the system RTC, which does not store timezone information. It's up to the OS to interpret the RTC time as being in some timezone or the other. Linux typically assumes the RTC time is in UTC, Windows typically assumes it's in the local timezone. So, when setting the time in Linux, if you give it time in IST, it will usually convert it to UTC and then store the UTC timestamp in the RTC.

In short: `date` is the wrong command for setting the timezone. The appropriate command would likely depend on which specific OS or distribution you are using. See, for example: [How to change the timezone on CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/248687/260978)